# RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BotBase.load_extension' was never awaited

Tags: python, python-3.x, бот, discord.py, discord

Я решил создать **cogs** своему боты, но у меня выходит такая ошибка:

Ошибка:

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BotBase.load_extension' was never awaited
self.load_extension(f'lib.cogs.{cog}')
```

Cogs.py

```
from discord.ext.commands import Cog

class Slash(Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @Cog.listener()
        async def on_ready(self):
            print('Cog is ready')

async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(Slash(bot))
```

Main.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot as BotBase
from glob import glob

OWNER_IDS = ['ids']
COGS = [path.split('\\')[-1][:-3] for path in glob('./lib/cogs/*.py')]

class Bot(BotBase):
def __init__(self):
    self.client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.all())

    super().__init__(command_prefix='!', owner_ids=OWNER_IDS, intents=discord.Intents.all())

def setup(self):
    for cog in COGS:
        self.load_extension(f'lib.cogs.{cog}')

def run(self):
    self.setup()
    self.VERSION = version

    with open('./lib/bot/token.0', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as tf:
        self.TOKEN = tf.read()
    super().run(self.TOKEN, reconnect=True)

async def on_ready(self):
    print('ready!')
```

Но когда я делаю **await self.load_extension(f'lib.cogs.{cog}')**, то мне говорит это:

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Bot.setup' was never awaited
self.setup()
```

А когда я делаю **await self.setup()** в функции **run**, то мне говорит это:

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Bot.run' was never awaited
bot.run(VERSION)
```

Вот код из **launcher.py**:

```
from lib.bot import bot

VERSION = '3.1.1.0'

bot.run(VERSION)
```

Код брал из видео:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sCfwkph7g_0&list=PLYeOw6sTSy6ZGyygcbta7GcpI8a5-Cooc&index=11

Название видео ролика: Introduction to cogs - Building a discord.py bot - Part 9

Answer (score 0):

Я решил эту проблему! Просто заменил **setup** на **setup_hook**, удалил вызов этой функции(setup_hook) в **run** и добавил **await** перед **self.load_extension(f'lib.cogs.{cog}')** и всё заработало!!!